# Custom Taxonomy - Dropdown

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I would like to create the same same Object  **wp_dropdown_categories**  creates, but this time using a custom query. I was to use $wpdb and create exactly the same effect.

**This is for a different project that uses the same WP database structure**

**Clarifications **

I created a Laravel 5.3 application and am coding a custom functionality for taxonomies, just like in Wordpress. It uses the same tables as in wordpress.i.e _terms , _term_taxonomy....

The _terms table has columns "term_id" "name" "slug" 
The _term_taxonomy table has columns "term_tax_id" "term_id" ..... and "parent". The two tables are joined by the "term_id" columns. The "parent" column stired the parent term_id

I can run the join query successfully, it only gets complicated when I get to isolate children and the levels of ancestry vis-à-vis the parent term_id.

I tried to check in Wordpress  /wp-includes/taxonomy.php but it is not clear, hence trying WPSE

In other words, I want to achieve what wp_dropdown_categories achieves, with a structure like I just explained.

Comment: Hello, welcome WPSE. No one will be able to answer your question with such little information. Please provide a code sample with a detailed explanation. And any research you have done on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you want to use a different taxonomy. Just change the 'category' value below to whatever your taxonomy name is.

```
<?php
  wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
  ) );
?>
```

For additional parameters, see the full list on the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Please check the more detailed description